# Show linear map is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ as:

$T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1+x_3, x_2-x_1, x_3)$

I know that every linear map is contiuous if the vector space $X$ is finite dimensional. But how can I prove this in particular?

Comment: Do you know the definition of continuity?

Comment: Can you prove that $x\mapsto x_1+x_3$ is continuous at $0$ on $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: It is enough to prove that T is continuous at 0

Comment: One approach would be to compute its operator norm relative to some vector norm. If a linear operator has finite norm then it is continuous. The relevant general theorem here is that all norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, so the operator norm of the matrix is at most some constant times the largest absolute value entry in the matrix.

Comment: Do you want to prove continuity or boundedness? *(Clearly, you know both are equivalent.)*

Answer (score 2):

Map $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$(not necesserally linear) is continious in given point $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ if for any arbitrary small $\varepsilon>0$ one can find $\delta >0$ such that for any $h\in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $||h|| < \delta$ we have
$$
||T(x+h)-T(x)||<\varepsilon.
$$
Here we can take any of the norm
$$
||(x_1,x_2,x_3)||_1 = |x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|,
$$
$$
||(x_1,x_2,x_3)||_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2},
$$
$$
||(x_1,x_2,x_3)||_{\infty} = \max_{1\le k \le 3}|x_k|,
$$
because in finite-dimensional spaces norms are equivalent. Let's take first norm for simplicity.

So take any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have for an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$
$$
||T(x+h)-T(x)||_1 = ||(h_1+h_3, h_2-h_1, h_3 )|| = |h_1+h_3|+|h_2-h_1|+|h_3|\le 3||h||_1.
$$ 
Now choose $\delta = \varepsilon/3$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Equivalence**

> For finite dimension:
>   $$r\|x\|'\leq\|x\|\leq R\|x\|'\quad(x\in X)$$

*(So we can freely choose!)*

**Boundedness**

Estimate the expression by:
$$\|T(x_1,x_2,x_3)\|_1=|x_1+x_3|+|x_2-x_1|+|x_3|\\
\leq2|x_1|+|x_2|+2|x_3|\leq2\|(x_1,x_2,x_3)\|_\infty$$

Concluding boundedness.

**Characterization**

> For products one has:
>   $$F\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y^\Lambda)\iff\pi_\lambda\circ F\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\quad(\lambda\in\Lambda)$$
>
> Especially it holds:
>   $$\pi_\lambda=\pi_\lambda\circ\mathrm{id}_X\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\quad(\lambda\in\Lambda)$$

*(So we can rip everything!)*

**Continuity**

Constant is continous:
$$\chi_{a}:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto a$$

Operations are continuous:
$$\alpha:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto x+y$$
$$\mu:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto xy$$

It writes as composition:
$$T=\alpha(\pi_2,\mu(\chi_{-1},\pi_3))$$

Concluding continuity.

Answer (score 0):

If $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map, then $T(x)=Ax$ for a unique $m\times n$ matrix $A$. By the cauchy schwartz inequality, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $||T(x)||\leq C||x||$ for some constant $C>0$. Therefore, $T$  is continuous.

As a result, all you really need to show is that $T$ is infact a linear map.